# IIS 8 not accepting connections from computers not on the domain

Tags: windows-8, iis

I'm trying to setup a basic website (static HTML file) on my computer (Windows 8 Pro) for testing. I can access the website from my local computer and from other computers on the domain, however I can't access it via any computer not connected to the domain (even if it is computer connected to the network but not joined to the domain).

I have setup port forwarding on the router. If I set the router to redirect port 80 to another computer on the network it works.

I have turned off the firewall completly to rule it out of the tests.

I have turned on anon. authentication and have set it to use my credentials.

When I try to connect to it from a computer that is not joined to the domain it refuses the connection. What else do I need to setup?

Comment: What error do you get? Check the IIS logs for the request that failed and note the status 40x and also the sub-status, the number next to it. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891/en-US for the meaning of the sub-statuses.

Comment: I've got a similar problem, local access to content (HTML, WCF services, etc.), but trying to browse from a remote machine times out with a 502 error